# Dell D620 died after upgrade to 22.04 Black Screen of Death. How can I saqve it?

Tags: upgrade, dell, 22.04

I have an older Dell D620 and I accepted the Upgrade from 20.04.
After the software finished downloading, the OS acted twerky and then after two restarts, i get only the black screen. No power at all, no lights, no nothing.
How can I revive my Dell?

Comment: That sounds like the hardware died to me, and you're asking a hardware question.  This is a Ubuntu Q&A site.

Comment: can you get into the BIOS and boot to a Live USB? If not, that is almost certainly a hardware issue. Contact Dell for assistance.

Comment: The laptop died after I installed Ubuntu 22.04. The data is still on the HD.

Comment: I discharged the excess power by taking out the battery and power cord and pressing the power button for a minute. Nothing happens. I was hoping people might have had a similar issue after downloading Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: It has NOTHING to do with Ubuntu except MAYBE incidentally if you actually tried to install Ubuntu and that very old and in its last legs hardware crapped  out. It's what we call a COINCIDENCE. Even more so if it just glitched after or during the installation ISO download, not the actual installation (your description isn't clear). NOT AN UBUNTU QUESTION!

Comment: If the data is still on the hard drive; you can *boot* a *live* system and copy the data off the drive and onto another device. I'm involved in QA-testing Ubuntu releases, and use hardware as old as from 2005 for current releases (using older hardware up to 19.04 or the *disco* cycle), and other than some old video cards not coping well with newer kernels, these issues were detectable well before an install was started; in fact install couldn't be started!  Your description fits hardware problems; but boot your machine BIOS & run your hardware tests - if you can't you have hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was a simple fix. The power button was not set right.
The problems did start after I reinstalled 20.4 after 22.04 used up so much resources that I couldn't open Firefox.
I went back to 20.4 on my other device as well.